# Add subject on email by share UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I use UIActivityViewController to share data.

My code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [text!], applicationActivities: nil)
    // This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
    
    // Anything you want to exclude
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
        UIActivityTypePrint,
        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
        UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
        UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
        UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
    ]
    
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)            
}
```

I can show SMS, email, and notes, and I can add body text in SMS, email, and notes. But I have a question for email: I only add the body text in the email, but I also want to add a subject for the email. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just set value of subject to your title like this:

```
activityViewController.setValue("This is my title", forKey: "Subject")
```

Comment: This seems to no longer work, at least not when sharing to MS Outlook.

Comment: This works only for iPhone Mail. Does not work for gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let obj = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [Text], applicationActivities: [])
  
obj.setValue("Your Subject", forKey: "Subject")
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of simply pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details

Answer (score 2):

Use this line of code to add the subject in the mail, but this will add the subject in default iOS mail, not in the google mail.

```
let string : String = "Hello this is content to Body of my mail."

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [string], applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.setValue("Subject Title",forkey "subject")

// This line of code will support alertcontroller as popover for iPAd also.                   
 if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
           popoverController.sourceView = super.view  
}

navigationController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true){
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the "setValue forkey" solution only works in specific context (i.e. not under macCatalyst), here a solution that worked for me :

```
class EmailSubjectActivityItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
var subject: String
var emailBody: String

init(subject: String, emailBody: String) {
    self.subject = subject
    self.emailBody = emailBody
}

func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
    return emailBody
}

func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
    
    if activityType == UIActivity.ActivityType.mail {
        return emailBody
    }
    return subject+"\n"+emailBody
}

func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
    if activityType == UIActivity.ActivityType.mail {
        return subject
    }
    return ""
}
```

}

How to use it ?

```
let emailTextAndSubject = EmailSubjectActivityItemSource(subject:"mysubject", emailBody:"myemailBody")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [emailTextAndSubject, WhateverAttachmentFileURL],
           applicationActivities: nil)
```